# Javascript Prompt() Input validation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling with the HTML code to validate the input of a Javascript prompt() in an external js file. I understand calling the Javascript function to validate and I know how to write the function, but how do you "listen" for the prompt and subsequent input in HTML?

Does the prompt have to be done in the HTML doc as a form?

Comment: Are you talking about the `window.prompt` function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt. If yes, there is no way to validate the input while typing. You can only validate the value *after* the user submits the value.

Comment: you don't listen for it, prompt() is sync, returning its result to whomever called it immediately upon closing the dialog.

Comment: Yes, window.prompt("Enter your name")

Comment: Must you use prompt()? The same code that displays the prompt command can display a jQueryUI dialog() box and then validate the input in the `close:` routine of the dialog. It really is simpler than it sounds -- Try [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZdFB/).  If you agree, then I'll post a standalone answer (you can figure it out, but it helps to see the <head> and sections that jsFiddle hides.

Comment: jQuery does seem to be the better option. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't wait around... Here is the code that I mentioned in my comment above. jsFiddle [live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/DZdFB/1/).

This is a fully working, stand-alone example. Just copy/paste into a file and run.

Note that you must reference / load the jQuery and jQueryUI libraries before the code itself (done here in the  tags).

Honestly, prompt() is a bad idea for websites these days. Perhaps this is more like what you want to do. Validation (of what the user typed) is done in the `close` section of the dialog.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $('#msg').dialog({
                        autoOpen:true,
                        modal:true,
                        title: 'This is a question:',
                        buttons: {
                            Go: function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        },
                        close: function() {
                            var s = $('#sumpin').val();
                            if (s.length<15)
                                alert('Please type more than 15 characters');
                            else
                                alert('You typed: ' + s);
                        }
                    });
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="msg" style="display:none">
        Type something here:<br />
        <input id="sumpin" type="text">
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

`prompt` is blocking. Whatever is entered into it is returned only after the OK button has been clicked (or enter has been pressed).

```
var foo = prompt('bar', 'baz');
if (some_condition(foo)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
    // (which might be to recursively call the function this code
    //  is inside until an acceptable result is received)
}
```

Comment: missing a bracket on line 2 :)

Comment: missing closing paren on line 1

Comment: @dandavis uh...no he isn't

Comment: not anymore, it was edited. looks like a rush to be the first led to a few missing keystrokes, it happens.

Comment: There was never an error on line one. There was a typo on line two, thanks to @imulsion for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

a prompt returns the value that you entered in the dialog window. use the returned value for whatever you want to do. like this:

```
var answer = prompt("<something>");
//stuff with answer
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/byt5a/)