# How to handle onkeypress() to restrict some characters on javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using below validation in HTML input

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="isNumber()"> 
<script>
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 43  && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

But, now I have to use this validation for javascript prompt.

```
var opening_time = prompt("enter customer mobile number to continue");
```

In this prompt, I need to use a javascript validation function.

> there is a possibility to validate the entered text after the close of
>   prompt. but i need to validate on typing. It must 'user can't type other than numbers' in prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Prompt() Input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218632/javascript-prompt-input-validation)

Comment: no, there is a possibility to validate the entered text after the close of prompt. but i need to validate on typing.

Comment: with onkeypress() event

Comment: Answers in that duplicate are the same you would get... You cannot.

Comment: It must 'user can't type other than numbers' in prompt.
but the  question having validation on close.

Comment: Make your own prompt or take a plugin which does this for you

Comment: so, there is no possible way to achieve this. 
ok, thank you